# Validating a url path with regex and excluding special characters

Tags: regex, path, regex-negation, regular-language, heap-analytics

I'm trying to write up an expression that starts with a '#" and takes in the following types of paths and only takes in a character A-z/a-z and doesn't accept digits or special characters:
Example valid paths:

```
#/
#/word/word
#/word
#/word/word/word
```

This is what I have currently:

```
#\/\D+|\/\D+
```

I have also tried:

```
#\/\D+|\s\/^[A-Za-z\s]*$
```

It filters 85% of the paths correctly but it still accepts paths with special characters as valid such as "#/word/word?test=word" "#/word/word=%"

I'm not quite sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would phrase the regex as:

```
^(?:#/|#/[A-Za-z]+(?:/[A-Za-z]+)*)$
```

This regex says to match:

- `^` from the start of the string
- `(?:`

  - `#/` match `#/` by itself
  - `|` OR
  - `#/` match `#/`
  - `[A-Za-z]+` followed by a path name
  - `(?:/[A-Za-z]+)*` followed by zero or more other paths
- `)`
- `$` end of the string

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can start the match with `#/` and then optionally match the trailing part:

```
^#\/(?:[A-Za-z]+(?:\/[A-Za-z]+)*)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `#\/` Match `#/`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[A-Za-z]+` Match 1+ chars A-Za-z
  - `(?:\/[A-Za-z]+)*` Optionally repeat `/` and 1+ chars A-Za-z
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/apjinE/1).